# como medir a velocidade no tráfego da banda larga móvel no 3g ou no wifi do celular programaticamente no iphone

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mono

No *app*, já estou fazendo a coleta do tráfego no iphone, agora preciso verificar como medir a velocidade no tráfego da banda larga móvel no *3g* ou no *wifi* do celular programaticamente.

Por exemplo:

A cada 1 minuto ou 10 minutos, ou mais, preciso saber qual é a velocidade média que os dados estão sendo entregues tanto para download ou upload, tanto pela rede *wifi* quanto pela rede *3g/4g* do celular.

Por favor, alguém sabe como fazer isso no iphone?

Comment: Faça um download de um arquivo razoavelmente grande (10MB no mínimo), medindo o tempo do download. Para medir o upload, faça o mesmo, mas enviando um arquivo.

Comment: não é isso, preciso saber a qual velocidade média que o celular está trafegando tanto na rede wifi quanto pelo 3G, vou editar minha pergunta e melhorar.

Comment: Periodicamente você verifica quanto foi trafegado então? Ou isto é feito verificando quanto foi trafegado até o momento? Se for o segundo caso, acredito não haver uma interface para isto.

Comment: Se pelo que entendi, sugiro que veja nestes dois sites: [Banda larga](http://www.portalhojeemdia.com/tecnologia/)/[Medidor de Velocidade](http://www.minhaconexao.com.br/)